# Clarification when using Mean Value Property to prove Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

We say that $f$ satisfies the Mean Value Property (MVP) on a ball $B(a,R) = \{z; |z-a| <R \}$ if 
$$ f(a) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} {\int_0}^{2\pi} f(a + te^{i \phi}) d \phi$$ for $0 < t <R.$

**It is easy to see , that a polynomial has the MVP on any ball of the complex plane**. proves that if $P$ is a polynomial which has no roots in a ball $B$ then the rational function $1/P$ has MVP on $B$. In particular if $P$ has no zeros in ${B_0}^R$ then:
$${1 \over P(0)} = {1 \over 2 \pi} {\int_0}^{2\pi} {d \phi \over P(t e^{i\phi})} \tag{1}$$

[Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra]
Assume, contrary to what we wish to prove, that there is a polynomial $P$ of degree $n \ge 1$ which has no zeros in $\mathbb{C}.$ Since we assume the degree of $P$ is at least one, $lim_{z\to \infty} 1/P(z) = 0$ there is $r>0$ such that:
$$ \frac{1}{|P(z)|} < \frac{1}{z |P(0)|}$$ for $ {|z| >r}.$
Applying equation (1) with $t>r$ leads to:
$$ \frac{1}{|P(0)|} \le \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{1}{2|P(0)|} 2\pi = \frac{1}{2|P(0)|} $$
This is a clear contradiction.

-
My question concerns primarily the assumption that it is easy to see that a polynomial has the MVP on any ball of the complex plane. WHY?

Comment: Are you aware of the result for harmonic functions? Alternatively, use the Cauchy integral formula on a monomial; the linearity of the integral gives you the rest.

Comment: Polynomial is the prototype of holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate consequence of  Cauchy's Integral Formula. Let $p: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a polynomial, thus
$$
p(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots +a_nz^n
$$ 
For $0<t<R$, let $\gamma:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$, given by $\gamma(\theta)=a+te^{i\theta}$($\{\gamma\} \subset B(a,R)$ ). Clearly $p$ is analytic on $B(a,t)$, then by Cauchy's Integral Formula
$$
p(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{p(z)}{z-a} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{p(a+te^{i\theta})}{te^{i\theta}}ite^{i\theta}\ d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(a+te^{i\theta})\ d\theta   
$$
Thus any polynomial has the MVP on any ball of the comlpex plane.